# How to perform bivariate optimization

Tags: r, optimization, grid

Is it possible to solve the following problem in R?

In particular, I want to find the values of a1 and a2 minimizing the loss below:

```
> n <- 1000
> x <- rnorm(n, 1, 1)
> e <- rnorm(n, 0, 1)
> d <- a1+a2*x+e < 0
> loss <- (mean(d) - 0.5) + (mean((a1 + a2*x + e)[d=0]) - 2)
```

That is, I want to find the values of a1 and a2 that make `mean(d)` and `mean((a1+a2*x+e)[d=0])` as close as possible to 0.5 and 2, respectively.

(the chosen values 0.5 and 2 are just temporal values)

Answer (score 1):

Using `optim` with a function `f` that computes the defined loss. `p` is a vector of parameters, i.e. `p[1]` is your *a1*, and `p[2]` your *a2*. Use reasonable starting values when calling `optim` with your function.

```
f <- \(p) {
  d <- p[1] + p[2]*x + e < 0
  (mean(d) - 0.5) + (mean((p[1] + p[2]*x + e)[d]) - 2)
}

res <- optim(c(0, 0), f)
res$par
# [1] 4.393432e+53 1.010012e+55  ## a1 and a2
```

Note that `d` is already boolean.

In case you get different results with different starting values, your distribution might be multi-modal.

---

*Data:*

```
n <- 1e3; set.seed(42); x <- rnorm(n, 1, 1); e <- rnorm(n, 0, 1)
```